# get_type_hints on TypeVar

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Given a function signature like this:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

def foo(arg: T) -> '?':
  return arg.op()
```

The return type of the function is the same as the return type of the "op" method of the type of arg. It seems to me that this information should be deducible by an IDE.

```
class SomeClass:
  def op() -> int:
    ...

x = foo(SomeClass()) # IDE should know that x has type 'int'.
```

Is there a syntax of type hinting how I can describe this dependency from the function signature of `foo`? In other words, by what expression should I replace `'?'` in the code above to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a TypeVar will not work here. Since your TypeVar is unconstrained (does not declare itself to be bounded by one or more types), you could substitute it for any arbitrary type -- object, int, str, float, Dict[str, List[str]]...

This means that with your current input type signature, the return type is inexpressible: given the inputs, there is sometimes just simply no valid return type.

More broadly, whether or not your tool is capable of inferring the return type is actually irrelevant here. The PEP 484 type system doesn't have a way to let you declare a return type that is based exclusively on something within the function body. Instead, you must either declare the return type is something fixed and concrete (like int or str) or is a generic type that is related to the input in some way.

There are two different ways of doing the latter.

First, you could insist that any class with the `op()` method inherits from some class, and have that class make the output of `op` be generic. For example:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

TOp = TypeVar('TOp')

class Operation(Generic[TOp]):
    def op(self) -> TOp: pass

class SomeClass(Operation[int]):
    def op(self) -> int:
        # ...snip...
        return 4

class OtherClass(Operation[str]):
    def op(self) -> str:
        # ...snip...
        return "output"

# Or alternatively, reuse the TOp variable from above -- it would mean the
# exact same thing, since TypeVars are only placeholders.
T = TypeVar('T')

def foo(arg: Operation[T]) -> T:
    return arg.op()

# Deduces the output types should be int and str respectively
a = foo(SomeClass())
b = foo(OtherClass())
```

Imposing these constraints on `arg` in turn lets us conclude what the return type must be.

The only disadvantage of this approach is that modifying SomeClass and OtherClass can perhaps be a bit intrusive. If you prefer against doing this, what you can do instead is to create a custom [Protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/):

```py
# Or, if you need to use older versions of Python, pip-install typing-extensions
# and do 'from typing_extensions import Protocol'.
from typing import Generic, Protocol, TypeVar

TOp = TypeVar('TOp')

# Doing 'class Blah(Protocol[T])' is a shorthand for
# doing 'class Blah(Protocol, Generic[T])'.
class SupportsOp(Protocol[TOp]):
    def op(self) -> TOp: ...

# SomeClass and OtherClass do *not* inherit SupportsOp!

class SomeClass:
    def op(self) -> int:
        # ...snip...
        return 4

class OtherClass:
    def op(self) -> str:
        # ...snip...
        return "output"

# Or alternatively, reuse the TOp variable from above -- it would mean the
# exact same thing, since TypeVars are only placeholders.
T = TypeVar('T')

def foo(arg: SupportsOp[T]) -> T:
    return arg.op()

# Still deduces the output types should be int and str respectively

a = foo(SomeClass())
b = foo(OtherClass())
```

The main difference is that Protocols use *structural subtyping* instead of *nominal subtyping*. With nominal subtyping, a type A is considered to be a subtype of B if A explicitly inherits from B. With structural subtyping, A is a subtype of B as long as its methods match the method signatures given in B.

---

Of course, whether or not your IDE will be capable for performing type inference for generics like these is a separate question. Type checkers like mypy will definitely have no issues, and IDEs like PyCharm usually seem to do a good enough job most of the time, but you may have to do some testing to see what is and isn't supported.